# How to get a list of version numbers for python packages released up until a specific date?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, python-packaging

Consider having a python `requirements.txt` file with a list of (un-versioned) dependencies (python packages). After you install them (e.g. `pip install -r requirements.txt`) you can call `pip freeze` and get a (**versioned**) list of all installed python packages.

This will be a snapshot of the python package versions (and their dependencies) available at the time. What I need to generate is this same list, but for a date in the past (let's say `2018-06-12`).

*I guess technically, I only need to find the released versions for all packages contained in the `requirements.txt` file.*

Ideally, there would be a command `pip install -r requirements.txt --before 2018-06-21` and then just call `pip freeze`, but I didn't see anything like that in `pip install --help`. I did see a way to specify another `--index-url` and I could imagine if there was an **archived** index from that date, I could point `pip` to that and it should work?

There is also a `--constraint` option, which:

> Constrain versions using the given constraints file

But I'm guessing I would already have to have the date-constraint versions in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, one possible answer (although not a great one) is to just manually go through each dependency in the `requirements.txt`, look that package up on https://pypi.org and then visit the release history (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/requests/#history). From there it's easy enough to see which version had been released at what date (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.19.0/ for `requests` when including `2018-06-12`) and then just use that as the version (`requests==2.19.0`).

A slightly better answer might be to extract that info (maybe via `curl`) from pypi programmatically, extract all version info (including the dates), sort it and pick the right one.

Answer (score 6):

From your question, if I get it right, you wanted to install dependencies with the following command:

`pip install -r requirements.txt --before 2018-06-21`

which require patching `pip` itself in order to add `--before` option to supply target date.

The code below it the second best thing. At the moment it is a rough sketch, but it does what you need, well almost, instead of generating `requirements.txt`, it outputs to the console the packages with the latest version up until the supplied date, in the format:

```
$ pipenv run python <script_name>.py django click --before 2018-06-21
pip install django==2.0.6 click==6.7
```

It's not exactly what you had in mind, but very close to it. Feel free to change it for your needs, by adding (or not) `-r` option and outputting every dependency on the new line, then with redirecting output, it would look something like that:

```
$ pipenv run python <script_name>.py django click --before 2018-06-21 >> requirements.txt
```

**Code (or just use link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/timjorjev/6079d981d8a8f4e1c5b6de554a5dbf32)):**

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import click

PYPI_URL = "https://pypi.org/project/{project_name}/#history"

def get_releases(request):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(request, 'html.parser')
    releases = list()

    for release in soup.find_all('div', class_='release'):
        release_version = release.find('p', class_='release__version').text.strip()
        if not is_numeric(release_version):
            continue
        release_date = try_parsing_date(release.find('time').text.strip())
        releases.append({'version': release_version, 'date': release_date})

    sorted_packages = sorted(releases, key=lambda s: list(map(int, s['version'].split('.'))))

    return sorted_packages


def is_numeric(s):
    for char in s:
        if not char.isdigit() and char not in [" ", ".", ","]:
            return False

    return True


def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%d.%m.%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%Y-%m-%d'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    click.echo('Not valid date format. Try to use one of this: <31.12.2018>, <31/12/2019> or <2018-12-31>')
    sys.exit(0)


@click.command(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help']))
@click.option('-b', '--before', help='Get latest package before specified date')
@click.argument('packages', nargs=-1, type=click.UNPROCESSED)
def cli(before, packages):
    target_date = try_parsing_date(before) if before else datetime.today()

    required_packages = list()
    not_found = list()

    for package in packages:
        project_url = PYPI_URL.format(project_name=package)
        r = requests.get(project_url)
        if r.status_code is not 200:
            not_found.append(package)
            continue

        releases = get_releases(r.text)
        last_release = None
        for idx, release in enumerate(releases):
            release_date = release['date']
            if release_date > target_date:
                if last_release and last_release['date'] <= release_date:
                    continue
            last_release = release

        required_packages.append({'package': package,
                                  'release_date': last_release['date'],
                                  'release_version': last_release['version']})


    print('pip install ' + ' '.join('{}=={}'.format(p['package'], str(p['release_version'])) for p in required_packages))
    if len(not_found) > 0:
        print('\nCould not find the following packages: {}'.format(' '.join(p for p in not_found)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

**Required dependencies (Python3):**

```
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
Click==7.0
requests==2.21.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried out the script, yet, but I hope it will be helpful for someone with the same question.

Comment: A neater solution should be possible with the PyPI API, such as https://pypi.org/pypi/numpy/json

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool that seems to fullfill your needs (still alpha):
https://pypi.org/project/pypi-timemachine/

As I read from its README, it creates a proxy to pypi.org which employs the date filter.

Comment: Didn't work for me - it tries to call `requests.get` within the tornado `ioloop`, which is single-threaded so just blocks indefinitely. I had to replace `requests` with tornado's `AsyncHTTPClient` and add the `nest_asyncio` package `nest_asyncio.apply()` call to get it to work.